# How to suggest a more balanced allocation of containers in Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, shuffle, reducers, mapper

How can I change/suggest a different allocation of containers to tasks in Hadoop? Regarding a native Hadoop (2.9.1) cluster on AWS.

I am running a native Hadoop cluster (2.9.1) on AWS (with EC2, not EMR) and I want the scheduling/allocating of the containers (Mappers/Reducers) would be more balanced than it is currently.
It seems like RM is allocating the Mappers in a Bin Packing way (where the data resides) and for the reducers, it seems more balanced.
My setup includes three Machines with replication rate three (all the data is on every machine) and I run my jobs with mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=0 in order to start shuffle as fast as possible (It is important for me that all the containers concurrently, it is a must condition).
In addition, according to the EC2 instances I have chosen and my settings of the YARN cluster, I can run at most 93 containers (31 each).

For example, if I want to have 9 reducers then (93-9-1=83) 83 containers could be left for the mappers and one is for the AM.
I have played with the size of split input (mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize, mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize) in order to find the right balance where all of the machines have the same "work" for the map phase.
But it seems like the first 31 mappers would be allocated in one machine, the next 31 to the second one and the last 31 in the last machine. Thus, I can try to use 87 mappers where 31 of them in Machine #1, another 31 in Machine #2 and another 25 in Machine #3 and the rest is left for the reducers and as Machine #1 and Machine #2 are fully occupied then the reducers would have to be placed in  Machine #3. This way I get an almost balanced allocation of mappers at the expense of unbalanced reducers allocation.
And this is not what I want...

`# of mappers = size_input / split size [Bytes],`

`split size=  max(mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize, min(mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize, dfs.blocksize))`

Answer (score 1):

I was using the default scheduler (Capacity) and by default `yarn.scheduler.capacity.per-node-heartbeat.maximum-container-assignments` was set to -1 (infinity) which explained why every node that answer first to the RM (with Heartbeat) has been "packing" containers as much as it can.
To conclude, inserting to hadoop/etc/hadoop/capacity-scheduler.xml the above parameter (using a third of the number of mappers would result in balanced scheduling of mappers) and following `yarn rmadmin -refreshQueues` after restarting the RM will grant you the option to balance the containers allocation in YARN.

For more details, please search my discussion [here](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@hadoop.apache.org:2019-01).